# Swift - Constructing a base Decodable struct with Generics

Tags: swift, generics, codable

So, I am trying to build a model that will be responsible for `URLRequest`s and parsing `Decodable`s. The response that is coming from the server is in the same form at the highest scope including keys `status`, `page_count` and `results`.

`results` values are changing respecting to the `request`,  `page_count` is optional and `status` is just a `String` indicating whether the `request` was successful or not.

I tried to implement `Generics` to `method` itself and base `Decodable` `struct` named `APIResponse` and below is an example of just one endpoint, named `extList`. The code compiles, however in the runtime it throws

> `Thread 7: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:`
>   `Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "results",`
>   `intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [],`
>   `debugDescription: "No value associated with key`
>   `CodingKeys(stringValue: \"results\", intValue: nil) (\"results\").",`
>   `underlyingError: nil))`

at the line of `json = try! JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse<T>.self, from: data)`

```
class NetworkManager {

    typealias completion<T: Decodable> = (Result<APIResponse<T>, Error>)->()

    class func make<T: Decodable>(of type: T.Type,
                                  request: API,
                                  completion: @escaping completion<T>){

        let session = URLSession.shared
        var req = URLRequest(url: request.url)
        req.httpMethod = request.method
        req.httpBody = request.body

        session.dataTask(with: req) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            var json: APIResponse<T>
            if let data = data,
               let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse?,
               response?.statusCode == 200 {
                switch request {
                case .extList:
                    json = try! JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse<T>.self, from: data)
                default:
                    return
                }
                completion(.success(json))
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Here is the base `struct`

```
struct APIResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    var status: String
    var page_count: Int?
    var results: T
}
```

Here is the response that should fill the `results` key in the `APIResponse` for this endpoint.

```
struct UserResponse: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var extens: Int
}
```

I am making my request as `NetworkManager.make(of: [UserResponse].self, request: .extList) { (result) in ; return }` and it works when I discard the `Response` generic type in the `APIResponse` with the `Array<UserResponse>` directly.

As requested, sample `json` I am trying to decode

```
{
    "status": "ok-ext_list",
    "page_count": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "some name",
            "extens": 249
        },
        {
            "name": "some other name",
            "extens": 245
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas to fix this?

> MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE

So the below code is working and I absolutely do not know why.

JSON's

```
import Foundation

var extListJSON : Data {
    return try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: [
        "status": "ok_ext-list",
        "page_count": 1,
        "results": [
            [
                "name": "some name",
                "extens": 256
            ],
            [
                "name": "some other name",
                "extens": 262
            ]
        ]
    ], options: .fragmentsAllowed)
}

var extListString: Data {
    return """
        {
            "status": "ok-ext_list",
            "page_count": 1,
            "results": [
                {
                    "name": "some name",
                    "extens": 249
                },
                {
                    "name": "some other name",
                    "extens": 245
                }
            ]
        }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!
}
```

Manager and Service

```
enum Service {
    case extList
}

class NetworkManager {

    typealias completion<T: Decodable> = (APIResponse<T>) -> ()

    class func make<T: Decodable>(of type: T.Type, request: Service, completion: completion<T>) {

        let data = extListString
        let json: APIResponse<T>

        switch request {
        case .extList:
            json = try! JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse<T>.self, from: data)
        }
        completion(json)
    }
}
```

Decodables

```
struct APIResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    var status: String
    var page_count: Int?
    var results: T
}

struct UserResponse: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var extens: Int
}
```

Finally method call

```
NetworkManager.make(of: [UserResponse].self, request: .extList) { (result) in
    dump(result)
}
```

Again, I have no clue why this is working. I just removed the networking part and it started to work. Just a reminder that my original code is working as well if I just use seperate `Decodable` for each `request` -without using `Generic` `struct`-. `Generic` `make(:_)` is working fine as well.

Comment: Can you add the json data that you're trying to decode?

Comment: add try catch to see error .. dont force cast ...

Comment: @NewDev json added.

Comment: @jawadAli with try catch added, it will work in the runtime yeah but it would not decode the response

Comment: @jawadAli it will throw the same error anyway

Comment: @Faruk that should work then. So, there's an error somewhere else that's not in this code.

Comment: @NewDev yeah, it should. but it does not somehow.

Comment: @Faruk, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then we could help debug this. If I straight up use your code (removing all the network stuff but keeping the generics) to decode the JSON you provided, it works as expected

Comment: @NewDev Ok, I'll let you know

Comment: @NewDev Hey, I tried to build a sample code in `Playground` and just without the networking part it working fine. I do not have any clue what I have been missing. You can check the edit.

Comment: @NewDev I even tried two different ways to create `Data` object from `json` to just to be sure.

Comment: @Faruk - so that **not** a reproducible example :) A reproducible example is one that reproduces the buggy behavior you're seeing. So, I can't help you debug this. But start with what's working and add the other functionality bit by bit until (and if) it stops working.

Comment: @NewDev yeah, technically :) but I could not make it not to work. Ok, I will start from scratch.

Comment: @NewDev Figured it out. Guess what did I see, when I tried to `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))`